# Formal smoothness over a DVR

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $S$ be the spectrum of a discrete valuation ring $R$, with fraction field $K$, algebraically closed residue field $k$, denote by $\varpi$ an uniformizer and by $o\in S$ the closed point. Let $\delta:X\rightarrow S$ be a projective morphism such that $X_K$ is a smooth $K$-variety. Let $x\in X_k$ be a closed point. Suppose that for every $j$ and $i$ mapping to $x$ and $o$ respectively there exists a morphism $Spec(R/\varpi^2)\rightarrow X$ commuting with the diagram below

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Spec(k) @>{j}>> X\\ 
@VVV @VVV \\ Spec(R/\varpi^2) @>{i}>> S
\end{CD}$$

Does this imply $\delta$ is (formally) smooth at $x$? (see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GZ for the definition of formal smoothness)

Comment: 1. Something's off in your diagram code and it's not quite rendering. 2. Where are you stuck in this problem? You appear to know the definition - what have you done so far to check that your situation satisfies it?

Comment: @Kreiser Sorry, I fixed the diagram now... It seems to me that, in this case, formal smoothness is equivalent to having the above infinitesimal lifting property with $Spec(R/\varpi^n)$ and $Spec(R/\varpi^m)$ instead of $Spec(R/\varpi^2)$ and $Spec(k)$ respectively, where $m\geq\lceil n/2\rceil$. I was trying to show that this is implied by the "first order infinitesimal lifting property" mentioned in the question. My intuition is that "smoothness" should be equivalent to "surjective differential", hence it should suffice to consider first order thickenings of $o$